# UITableView DequeueReusableCell sometimes creates new items despite already created more than items on screen, reusing "only" cca 80-95% times

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I have a UITableView with different cell types. For one type(smallest, I have different Height from 40 to like 1000px), only a few items are in queue and when scrolling up/down these few (typically 5) are reused and some (2-3) are created new ones.

What is unpleasant is, that these cells takes a lot of memory (drawn by SkiaSharp - SKCanvasView) and for every scroll up/down 2-3 are created new ones, the old ones are not being destroyed/Disposed. (Using only WeakReference, etc.. but still I don't know why).

So I I have a table with 300 items, after 100x scrollings up/down, I have created like 205 objects, causing memory leak.

I would call Dispose on them, If I would know that UITableView is not going to reuse cell, but I suppose there is no such event.

What is the best approach to solve this memory leak? How big is UITableView reuse queue? I suppose that problem is, that reuse queue is full, UITableView doesn't want to keep more items in queue and discards them. But Xamarin keeps them in RAM.

On Android I have recycler view, I know about PoolSize for every item, I have an event when item is going to be recycled etc...

Comment: Hi - you'll more likely get some responses if you provide [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem… including things like code etc helps people understand where things could be going wrong

Comment: As Craig said share some code. As for the TableView, it will create as many cells are required to fill the screen. So if the screen height is 400 px and cell is 40px, it will create 10 cells and then reuse those. If screen is 400px and cell is 80px it will create 5 cells, etc...